# autoplay video on mobile don't work on production

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

when I tested it on chrome dev mode it works great,
on production i got this:
[autoplay video on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4VQ2.jpg) iPhone xs ios 13.3

code:

```
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
<source src="videos/1.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=vp9,vorbis">
<source src="videos/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

any ideas?

Comment: iOS Safari does not always autoplay html5 video. Its a setting on every device, something to do with low-power-mode

Comment: you right, the low-power mode now off and it works! thanks